# Can Our Own "Frontend Web Application" & "Third Party Custom Applications" be authenticated against RESTful backend?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-web-api, digital-signature, restful-authentication

I'm currently developing restful backend and implementing the authentication, i want my both frontend(web interface) and api(third party applications) to use same backend. As i have same set of features for both frontend and api.

Here is the approach that I am thinking off currently:

1) The REST API should look for two different kinds of information in the security header section:

- A: API Key + API Sign - when Third Party Applications connect
- B: Access Token - when Frontend Application connects

Either one of them should be present & never both.

2) In our REST API will have login method as well. Which will take username and password as input and return an "Access Token" in response. The validity period of access token should be as much as user has specified for his auto logout functionality. The tokens should be one time only and simply impossible to guess.

So my questions am i on the right way? or are there any other solutions? Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Sure I think you should checkout the Keystone framework. Keystone is the Openstack authentication framework and is easy to plug into and backend you may have. You can set token privs and any kind of groups you want.

http://docs.openstack.org/developer/keystone/